# Formula similar to $EX=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq i\right)$ to compute $E(X^n)$?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Is there a formula like 
$$
EX=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq i\right)
$$

(which can be found on  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values)  and holds for positive $X$)
for $EX^{n}$ ?

And I don't mean this one,

$$
EX^{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq\sqrt[n]{i}\right),
$$

which is immediate, if we take $Y=X^{n}$ and use the above formula
for $Y$. I mean a "more elegant" one - if there is one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One has

> $$
> \mathrm E(X^n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty(i^n-(i-1)^n)\,\mathrm P(X\geqslant i).
> $$

More generally,

> $$
> \color{red}{\mathrm E(u(X))=u(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty(u(i)-u(i-1))\,\mathrm P(X\geqslant i)}.
> $$

To prove this, call $(\ast)$ the RHS and note that $\mathrm P(X\geqslant i)=\sum\limits_{k=i}^\infty\mathrm P(X=k)$, hence
$$
(\ast)=u(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty(u(i)-u(i-1))\,\sum_{k=i}^\infty\mathrm P(X=k),
$$
that is,
$$
(\ast)
=
u(0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathrm P(X=k)\sum_{i=1}^ku(i)-u(i-1)
=u(0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathrm P(X=k)(u(k)-u(0)),
$$
and, finally,
$$
(\ast)
=
u(0)\mathrm P(X=0)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathrm P(X=k)u(k)=\mathrm E(u(X)).
$$

Comment: The same way you get the original, write $P(X \ge i) = \sum_{k=i}^\infty P(X=k)$ and interchange the sums.