# If $E(X^2)=3, E(X)=1$, find $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X \geq i)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $E(X^2)=3, E(X)=1$, find $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X \geq i)$

Hint given:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X \geq i)=\frac12\left[E(X^2)-E(X)\right]$

My attempt:

From [Formula similar to $EX=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}P\left(X\geq i\right)$ to compute $E(X^n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143097/formula-similar-to-ex-sum-limits-i-1-inftyp-leftx-geq-i-right-to-compu), I know that $E(X^n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \{i^n-(i-1)^n\} P(X \geq i)$

Now, $E(X^2)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \{i^2-(i-1)^2\} P(X \geq i)$

$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} (2i-1) P(X \geq i)$

Similarly, $E(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \{i-(i-1)\} P(X \geq i) =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq i)$

This gives me $\frac12[E(X^2)+E(X)]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} i P(X \geq i)$

which would give my result as $\frac{3+1}{2}=2$, instead of the given answer $1$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You can easily check again a few distributions to determine if either of the hint or your equation is false.

Comment: Do we have $P(X\geq0)=1$? And presumably, $X$ is discrete?

Comment: @Arthur The only other information given is "X is a non-negative integer valued random variable".

Comment: That's exactly what I'm wondering about, just with different words. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$. Then $E[X^2]-E[X]=0$, but $1\cdot P(X\geq 1)=1/2$, so the hint is wrong, and you're right.